# How to turn a cut string into a float (python)?

Tags: python, string, list, numbers, typeerror

I am making a grade calculator program that takes grades as strings, takes a part of that string and converts it to a float, and then adds that float to a variable.

```
homework = ['10/10', '8/10', '4/10']

pointsearned = 0.0

def addpts(list):
    for grade in list:
        global pointsearned
        pointsearned = pointsearned + float(list[grade][:list.index('/')])

addpts(homework)

print pointsearned
```

I get the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: Use int(grade) at index.

Comment: Also don't call lists `list` - it blocks access the the builtin.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all don't use list as variable name since it is inbuilt python keyword
2. In your code you are using `list[grade]` but grade is element in list not index that's why you are getting error. Also you are using `list.index('/')`
   but  in your list there is no element `\`. I changed the code. Check blow

`homework = ['10/10', '8/10', '4/10']
pointsearned = 0.0
def addpts(lst):
    for grade in lst:
        global pointsearned
        pointsearned = pointsearned + float(grade.split('/')[0])
    return pointsearned
print addpts(homework)`
`#print pointsearned`

Comment: Use return value instead of globals. Global values are a bad idea in general, and certainly in this case in particular.

Comment: @CadeB.: Yes prefer using return instead of global variable and printing inside function. I changed code as per Mad Physicist comments.

Comment: @CadeB.: If it answers your question ,mark as answered